# Are there any strict rules which can be imposed on Magnus Carlsen for resigning on purpose against Hans?

Tags: fide, carlsen, cheating

There has already been a lot of chess drama going on between Hans and Magnus after Carlsen [withdrew](https://twitter.com/MagnusCarlsen/status/1566848734616555523?cxt=HHwWhsC4ueynyL4rAAAA) from Sinquefield Cup 2022(before losing his last match against Hans). There have been many [theories/speculations about cheating by Hans](https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/40576/if-hans-niemann-is-cheating-how).

After all of this started the Generations Cup. Yesterday Magnus Carlsen faced Hans Niemann in the [Round 6th](https://www.chess.com/news/view/2022-julius-baer-generation-cup-day-2) of the ongoing [Generations Cup](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&ved=2ahUKEwjrr-_tzKP6AhU1xDgGHS0xDy4QFnoECDcQAQ&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.chess.com%2Fevents%2F2022-champions-chess-tour-julius-baer-generation-cup-prelims&usg=AOvVaw3Aqy6pZvykiTv5q_RXtYgA). Magnus resigned after move two and left his room. This act by Carlsen heated up the situation very quickly. Many people are against him for this "**Poor sportsmanship**" behavior. Some even consider this as breaking FIDE's rules of **respecting players** and their **sandbagging policy**.

Are there any strict FIDE rules for this? If yes, is it possible that FIDE can take any action against Magnus Carlsen for his behavior against Hans?

Comment: It's an online tournament, so I suspect FIDE's rules aren't involved. But I might be wrong.

Comment: @RemcoGerlich i was wondering how magnus won the fairplay award for resigning against Ding. if i remember it was not a fide event

Comment: "Carlsen resigns hopeless position after blundering against Niemann again."

Comment: "Resigning on purpose" is a strange phrasing.  How often does one resign accidentally?

Comment: Could blunder and resign. but usually still plays out the game for a while

Comment: @NoamD.Elkies: People have resigned in won positions :-) But that most probably isn't the way you use "accidentally" here...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> Are there any strict FIDE rules for this?

Strictly speaking this is an online tournament organized by chess24.com and is not FIDE rated. That means it is not under FIDE jurisdiction nevertheless [FIDE Laws of Chess](https://handbook.fide.com/chapter/E012018) apply.

There is no rule which says you are not allowed to resign after making only one move. The only rule which might apply is in **Article 11: The conduct of the players** where it says:

> 11.1 The players shall take no action that will bring the game of chess into disrepute.

This is a judgment call which would have to be made by the chief arbiter in consultation with the organizer(s). In this case I cannot see chess24.com making any decision against Carlsen for the simple reason that he is a business partner. They may also believe that the extra publicity it attracts is good for their business and the advertising they are selling off the back of the tournament.

> is it possible that FIDE can take any action against Magnus Carlsen for his behavior against Hans?

Not for this tournament because it is not a FIDE tournament. FIDE have no control over the players or the tournament.

> Will FIDE take any action after Magnus Carlsen resigned on purpose against Hans?

Currently for a game to be rated there has to be at least one move by each player. Carlsen was careful not to break this rule even though the tournament is not FIDE rated.

There is nothing that FIDE can do directly (because they don't have jurisdiction over this tournament) but they could contemplate a rule change. If they did this it would take some time and have to be considered carefully.

The last time they did something like this was more than 40 years ago. In the last round of tournament English GM Tony Miles was paired against Stewart Reuben. Miles only needed a draw to win the tournament and generous first prize. The night before they agreed to a draw and on the day they played no moves and just wrote the result. At the time this was not against the rules.

This result also gave Reuben a share of second prize. Initially the prizes were awarded but when the organizers realized what had happened they reclaimed the prizes and cancelled the result of that game. It caused a storm and resulted in FIDE changing the rules to require at least one move be made by each side.