# Why wasn't Magnus sanctioned for cheating Danya TWICE on lichess?

Tags: rules, etiquette, lichess, cheating, famous-events

Magnus [cheated](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/88625/would-it-be-have-been-unhelpful-for-hans-niemann-to-bring-up-magnus-carlsens) Daniel 'Danya' Naroditsky [TWICE](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0PtPepfwBPg) on lichess:

1. 2020 - got help from [Aryan Tari](https://lichess.org/l2wS1g9X/white#43)
2. 2021 - got help from [David Howell](https://lichess.org/w1j9cz4v#20) (soon after Magnus cheated [Ian 'Nepo' Nepomniachtchi](https://www.reddit.com/r/chess/comments/164y1sx/magnus_carlsen_cheated_over_the_board_in_the/) in the 2021 classical WCC)

The CEO of chessable, [Geert van der Velde](https://twitter.com/blackatlantic/status/1577712056710696968), even brought this up in 2022Sep with the [Hans Niemann vs Magnus](https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/40576/if-hans-niemann-is-cheating-how/45044#45044) controversy.

**Question**: Why wasn't Magnus sanctioned for either of these?

I understand that touch move is something to be claimed by opponent during the game, so that's why Magnus wasn't sanctioned for cheating Nepo. Same reason as when [Magnus cheated Alireza Firouzja in 2019 blitz WCC](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YPysTEW0YZU).